# number of map output records less than combine input records in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I run a mapreduce I am getting combine input records greater than map output records? This is really strange. I could not figure out exactly whats happening? As far as I know map output records should be exaclty same ad combine input records. Could anyone please help me figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Here is a real world job example:

```
    Map-Reduce Framework
      Map input records=112705844
      Map output records=64841776
      Combine input records=64842079
      Combine output records=409
      Reduce input records=106
      Reduce output records=4
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the behavior how combiners are applied was changed from Hadoop 0.18 onwards. Before a combiner was called exactly once per map task. Now it can be called 0 or more times on both the map and the reduce side. Which suggests that the counts of the combiner input/output records do not have to match exactly to the map/reduce input/output counts.